# Add another forwarded email address to Gmail without SMTP server

Tags: gmail

I have a domain name on DNSimple, with email forwarding to my Gmail account.

It's working well, except I would like to be able to send emails from Gmail using my DNSimple's email.

But when I go on Gmail settings, and click the *Add another email address you own* link and set my DNSimple email and *Next step* button, Gmail ask me for an SMTP password. And I have no idea about it.

If I correctly remember, at the beginning of Gmail it was automatic.

Any solutions?

Comment: So DNSimple doesn't require you to use a password when logging into your email? Have you tried the password you use to log into DNSimple?

Comment: To send/receive emails, I just have to login inside Gmail and that's fine. Now I also would like to write emails with Gmail selecting my DNSimple email address as the A: field of Gmail.

Comment: Ok have you tried leaving the password field blank?

Comment: Yes. Actually I followed the doc: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347?hl=en ; and I'm blocked between step 4 and 5. Maybe it's because this external email address is forwarded to Gmail server, and so the SMTP server is the Gmail one. Kinda exotic?

Answer (score -1):

Gmail recently changed its policy. Now it does not permit anymore to use the Gmail SMTP server to send email on behalf of another domain. This is to avoid spammers and enforce some security policy.

So, if you have an address aaa@bbb.com you also must have an SMTP server for bbb.com (e.g. smtp.bbb.com) and an account on that SMTP server. If you have those, you can enter that information in Gmail and set up that account as an alias.

Essentially, Gmail becomes just a client for that address, using the address’ SMTP server instead of Gmail’s SMTP server, to send mail for that address.

You can continue to use the Gmail SMTP server to send mail only for other Gmail addresses, or for Google Apps addresses.

Comment: Please don't leave the same answer to multiple questions.  If the questions are essentially duplicates, please flag one of them to be closed.  Thanks!